# Using direct field access instead of getters in a copy constructor leads to null pointer exception

Tags: java, hibernate, copy-constructor, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

It must be Java 101 but I can't figure why I can't use direct field access and why I'm forced to use getters in a copy constructor.

I have a bunch of entities. They are organised like a tree. Linked entities are fetched eagerly.

I'm using Hibernate, Lombok and IntelliJ for the debugger.

When I pull one of the entity trees by the root I get a tree of objects. Let's call it "the original". For some reason  related to business requirements I need to copy it (let's call this "the copy"). I do it using a copy constructor.
I first wrote a version of the copy constructor using direct field access.

```
 this.someField= original.someField
```

It didn't work. When I checked the debugger I saw that original.someField (as well as the other fields) were always null.

[image]

Nevertheless, it works using the getters.

```
 this.setSomeField(original.getSomeField())
```

In the debugger, I can see the fields are "set" in original.handler.target. (I've no idea what handler.target is).

[image]

Could someone explain to me why a direct field access doesn't work ?
(I'm asking about the technical reason not the philosophical one like "you should always use getters" etc).

I'd also be glad to know what is "handler.target".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code that does the copying and how you call said code

Comment: @Lino it's just a bunch of "this.someField= original.someField" statements. There is nothing else to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have encountered is not at all Java 101 problem. Hibernate has a feature called lazyloading, that allows the framework to defer the loading of an (potentially heavy) object to a later point in time, **only when it is needed**. This comes handy when you are for example loading an `account` object just to check an `active` flag, but absolutely do not need all the login history fetched with this account.

**Now the "only when it is needed" part**: getters.

Hibernate knows that you do need that lazily loadable object when you do call the getter on the parent object in the object graph. Until you do so, the lazily referred object remains null. Direct variable access bypasses the proxylogic that performs this "trick", and that is how you get to the unexpected null values. when the field is accessed via its getter, the proxied code kicks in, loading happens, and you get your object back.

*The `handler/target/etc` are just the extra references you need to hvae due to the proxying. (your `account` will not have an direct `accounthistory` variable anymore, but instead an `accounthistory_proxy`, which in turn will have an `accounthistory_real`)*

Comment: Thanks. I thought Hibernate would only lazy load entities in a relationship if the fetch type isn't "EAGER", but would load the entity fields.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are getting proxy object, once you are calling getter method you will get actual object.Please can you check once you are calling gettter method after that still the fields of object are null ? Try to use . operator after calling getter, I think values in fields should come.